# Doleans Dade Product Compensator

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ be martingales, $X_0 = Y_0 = 0$.

Can the stochastic exponential $\mathcal{E}(X+Y+[X,Y]) _t$ be written on the form of $\mathcal{E}(X+Y)_t  \exp (C_t)$  for some sort of "compensator" $C_t$? And if yes and not obvious what properties will it have?

The motivation stems from if $X,Y$ are continuous then
$$
\mathcal{E}(X+Y+[X,Y])_t  = exp ( X_t+Y_t+[X,Y]_t - 1/2 [X+Y+[X,Y]]_t] ) 
= exp ( X_t+Y_t - 1/2 [X+Y] ) exp ( [X,Y]_t)  = \mathcal{E}(X+Y)_texp ( [X,Y]_t) 
$$
Since $[X,Y]_t$ is continuous and of finite variation, so then simply $C_t =  [X,Y]_t$.